# Use a Perl Script to read a line of data from a file, and display?

Tags: perl

I need some help with a script I am trying to create. Basically I have about 30 txt files, each with a email address field. for example:

```
example@hotmail.com
```

I want to be able to use a Perl script to read all of the 30 txt files, returning a list of all email addresses.

Each txt file is located in the same location, and is named like this:
1.txt, 2.txt etc.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Oh, great. Do you work for one of those spam factories? :)

Comment: I haven't tried anything, I work in IT support and I need to find out how many emails different users (by email address) have logged.

Comment: @user900897: Around here, it's more appreciated if you've tried something first or put in some kind of effort. You should go to perl.org, look through the documentation and examples, try some code, etc. You'll get some help here occasionally without effort, but effort gets more answers, and better answers.

Comment: CPAN is the way to go. Do not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know any Perl? I don't mind helping people with their issues, but writing code is my job, and I like to get paid for it.

Here are some hints:

- To read in the files, use the [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) module. That'll help you find all the files you need to read in.
- You can use a hash to guarantee unique email addresses.

For example:

```
my %emailHash;
while (my $line = <FILE>) {
    chomp $line;
    if ($line =~ /[^[^\@]+\@[^\@]+\.[\w+]$/) {   #Email address
        $email{$line} = 1;
    }
}
```

Now, you can use the [keys](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) function to print them out:

```
 foreach my $email (sort keys %emailHash) {
    print "Email: $email\n";
 }
```

Comment: `File::Find` is good if the files are in multiple directories within a tree.  If they're all in a single directory (and it seems that they are), `readdir` is sufficient.